# Loop through JSON NSDictionary

Tags: php, ios, json, nsarray, nsdictionary

I am trying to print MySQL result sets with PHP in JSON format, and read it with iOS.

This is my **JSON-string**:

```
[{"partnerid":"1","code":"SUMU6003","partnerName":"Company name","street":"Some Street 5323","zipCode":"8732","city":"Berlin","languages":"English","workers":"Name 1, Name 2","lineup":"Kids"},{"partnerid":"2","code":"DEMO8884","partnerName":"Partner 2","street":"Third street 2","zipCode":"383838","city":"Berlin","languages":"Greek","workers":"Petra","lineup":"Kids"}]
```

In this **method** I get the `NSDictionary`:

```
#pragma mark - ServiceConnectorDelegate -

-(void)requestReturnedData:(NSData *)data { 
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithJSONData:data];
    # process dictionary and grep strings from json-string
    # ...
}
```

Can you please tell me how to access the different result sets in a loop? I want to access each key separately.

I know that the `NSDictionary` contains data, because `NSLog(@"%@",dictionary);` prints:

```
2012-12-20 19:13:20.661 myapp[576:907] (
        {
        city = Berlin;
        code = SUMU6003;
        languages = English;
        lineup = Kids;
        partnerName = "Company name";
        partnerid = 1;
        street = "Some Street 5323";
        workers = "Name 1, Name 2";
        zipCode = 8732;
    },
        {
        city = Berlin;
        code = DEMO8884;
        languages = Greek;
        lineup = Kids;
        partnerName = "Partner 2";
        partnerid = 2;
        street = "Third street 2";
        workers = Petra;
        zipCode = 383838;
    }
)
```

Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: That's not a "JSON dictionary".  It's a JSON array containing multiple JSON objects.  JSON array == NSArray.  JSON object == NSDictionary.  When you NSLog the "dictionary" it's printing out an NSArray of NSDictionaries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes introspection can be useful here.  For instance NSLog(@"dictionary is of type: %@", [dictionary class]);

The reason I say that is based on your output it appears that dictionary is in fact an array containing two NSDictionaries.  If that is the case you would want to do something like this:

```
for (NSDictionary *actualDictionary in dictionary<this is really an array>)
{
  NSString *myStringValue = [actualDictionary objectForKey:@"city"];
  // etc...
}
```

You have to find out what data types your actually dealing with first though.

Comment: It returns: dictionary is of type: __NSCFArray

Comment: Which is exactly what one would expect.

Comment: Yes, that means the loop I laid out for you above should do the trick.

Comment: Hi HackyStack, exactely what I've been looking for, thank you very much and Merry Christmas!

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

`#import <objc/runtime.h>`

`NSLog(@"The class name is %s", object_getClassName(dictionary);`

Answer (score 0):

the response dictionary you have is containing **array of dictionaries** so you can run the dictionary values by fast enumerating the dictionary and cast each as dictionary and get its value like the following :

```
-(void)requestReturnedData:(NSData *)data { 
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithJSONData:data];
    # process dictionary and grep strings from json-string
    for(id item in dictionary ) 
    {
        NSDictionary *dic = (NSDictionary *)item;
        NSLog(@"%@",[dic objectForKey:@"city"]);
        NSLog(@"%@",[dic objectForKey:@"code"]);
        ......
    }
 }
```